# How do I get the Armor Pencil?

Tags: draw-a-stickman-epic

I've heard rumors that there's a secret "Armor Pencil". How do I get it?

Comment: To whoever edited my original question: As stated in the first part of my answer, the Armor Pencil can only be acquired in-game in the Steam version of the game. It is available as paid DLC in the other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non-Steam versions of the game, the Armor Pencil is available as paid DLC. In the Steam version of the game, you have to find it to unlock it.

After you've unlocked the Volcanic Valley stage, go there. Once you've crossed the bridge made from two fallen-over rocks, go north. When you reach the north wall, you'll find a helm.

[image: Helm and drawings]

The paintings on the wall show what you need to do to the helm: Rain, rain, lightning, rain. Once you've done those four things in the correct order, the helm will fall over and a bridge will materialize in the southwest section of the map.

[image: New bridge and hidden area]

Go south and stand on the new bridge. Use lightning to light the dynamite and stun the fire-breathing rocks. The large rock will explode, revealing the Armor Pencil. Go collect your reward.